# Parsing non-alphanumeric characters in QueryParser

Tags: c++, lucene

I am working on a former team mate's code using Lucene++ 3.0.3.

There is a comment that claims QueryParser cannot handle "special characters" and one way this has been handled is to replace "special characters" with a space:

```
if (((*pos) >= L'A' && (*pos) <= L'Z') ||
    ((*pos) >= L'a' && (*pos) <= L'z') ||
    ... ||
    (*pos == L'-'))
{
    // do nothing, these are OK
} else {
    // remaining characters are []{}*
    (*pos) = L' ';
}
```

`StandardAnalyzer` is the Analyzer being used. (Thanks [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076249/mark-leighton-fisher))

I assume the "special characters" are for combining queries or some sort of wildcard processing, for want of a better term.

Is there a better function that can account for these characters within a query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at what Analyzer is used, as the Analyzer determines the Tokenizer used (and the Tokenizer determines which characters are special).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through that again and see. Right now at least I intend to invert the conditions, since the set to be replaced is much smaller:

`if ((*pos == L'[') || ... ) (*pos) = L' ';`